# How may I create the area bar like the below Image in Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-cs4, photoshop-cs3

How may I create the Area Bar like the below Image Bar on the Top and Bottom too for Area? I search a lot but didn't find it that how may I make it?

[image: click here]

Answer (score -1):

You can use **rectangular marquee tool** and fill the desired color.

`Marquee tool` have `add and subtract` option too by which you can make `different shapes` also according to your image.